# How to make modal popup gain focus in a webview?

Tags: android

In my Android app I am displaying a webpage. Sometimes the webpage opens up a modal popup/dialog but the scrolling focus remains in the webpage and not in the popup. How do I control the focus here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a WebAppInterface to show dialogs.

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

And set this Interface at your WebView

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

This creates an interface called Android for JavaScript running in the WebView. At this point, your web application has access to the WebAppInterface class. For example, here's some HTML and JavaScript that creates a toast message using the new interface when the user clicks a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
}
```

There's no need to initialize the Android interface from JavaScript. The WebView automatically makes it available to your web page. So, at the click of the button, the showAndroidToast() function uses the Android interface to call the WebAppInterface.showToast() method.

Fount: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: This is not a native dialog that I want to show over the webview. The webpage opens its own modal popup dialog with a lot of content in it, but the focus sometimes remains in the underlaying webpage.